# Prove $(1-x)\ln(1-x)+(1+x)\ln(1+x)\leq 2x^2$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> Find the smallest value of $c$ such that $(1-x)\ln(1-x)+(1+x)\ln(1+x)\leq c x^2$ holds for $0<x<1$.

I saw the curve and realized this is true for $c=2$. How can I prove it? What is the smallest $c$ that still makes the inequality valid?

I think we should use the Taylor expansions of the $\ln$s.

Comment: Just curious.  Why do you have to write $... \leq  cx^2$, where $c=2$?  Wouldn't it be more concise to simply write $ ...\leq 2x^2$?

Comment: @Batominovski If you read the question completely, you will see I am looking for the smallest $c$.

Comment: I see.  The wording could be less confusing, though.

Comment: @Batominovski Can you tell me how I can write it better? I want to learn.

Comment: See my edit.  I think it looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the smallest value of $c$, use the following method:

Assume $(1-x)\ln (1-x) + (1+x)\ln (1+x) = cx^2$. You have a function in two variables. You can (if it makes it easier for your to visualize), replace $c$ with $y$. Now, you have $y(x)$. Use techniques of calculus to maximize the function.

$$\dfrac{(1-x)\ln (1-x) + (1+x) \ln (1+x)}{x^2} = c$$

With a little calculus, you will find that the derivative has no roots in the reals. So, you need to look at limits.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(1-x)\ln (1-x) + (1+x) \ln (1+x)}{x^2} = 1$$

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{(1-x)\ln (1-x) + (1+x) \ln (1+x)}{x^2} = \ln (4) \approx 1.386$$

That would be our minimum value for $c$.

$$c\ge \ln(4)$$

Comment: I'd like to see the argument that the derivative has no roots.

Comment: $$\dfrac{dc}{dx} = \dfrac{(x-2)\ln (1-x) - (x+2) \ln (1+x) }{x^3}$$

Setting that equal to zero, we are looking for $$(x-2)\ln(1-x) = (x+2)\ln(1+x)$$

Rewriting, we are looking for $$(1+x)^{x+2}(1-x)^{x-2} = 1$$ which can obviously only happen when $x=0$. Plug in any value $0<x<1$ and find that the derivative is positive over the entire interval.

Comment: Perhaps it is not so easy to see why it is obviously only equal at $x=0$. It seemed intuitive to me, but now that I try to think why that must be the case, I am drawing a blank to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

The radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series of $(1-x)\log(1-x)+(1+x)\log(1+x)$ is one.
In explicit terms
$$\begin{eqnarray*} (1-x)\log(1-x)+(1+x)\log(1+x) &=& x^2+\frac{x^4}{6}+\frac{x^6}{15}+\frac{x^8}{28}+\ldots\\&=&x^2+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{x^{2n}}{n(2n-1)} \end{eqnarray*}$$
hence
$$ f(x)=\frac{(1-x)\log(1-x)+(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2} = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n}}{(n+1)(2n+1)} $$
is an increasing function on $(0,1)$, ranging from $1$ to $\color{red}{2\log 2}$, which is the optimal $c$-constant.
An improved inequality is $f(x)\leq x^2+(2\log 2-1)x^4$. An improved lower bound is $f(x)\geq \frac{x^2}{1-x^2/6}$.

Comment: @MarkViola: Indeed $f(x)\geq 1$ on $(0,1)$, and $f(x)\leq 2\log 2\leq 2$, which is OP's original claim.

Comment: $f(x)$ only has non-negative coefficients in its Maclaurin series, hence it is an increasing function over $(0,1)$ and its sup is exactly given by $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=2\log 2$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that for $t>0$

$$\log(t)\le t-1$$

Comment: Thanks. How can we find the smallest $c$ here?

Comment: As you had surmised, use of Taylor series is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- $\ln(1+x)\le x$
- $\ln(1-x)\le -x$

therefore

$$(1-x)\ln(1-x)+(1+x)\ln(1+x)\le -x+x^2+x+x^2= 2x^2$$

Comment: Thanks. How can we find the smallest $c$ here?

Answer (score 1):

Idea to find smallest $c$: Write $f(x):=\dfrac{(1−x)\ln(1−x)+(1+x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$ and use calculus to find local maximums or determine if the functions is increasing or decreasing. If the function is increasing or decreasing on $(0,1)$, the smallest value of $c$ can be found by taking a limit at the appropriate endpoint.

Comment: This will not actually work, though.  This function does not have a local minimum, unless you do something to it.

Comment: @Batominovski Edited to add what to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Another hint**:

If $1>x>0$, one has $\;\ln(1-x)<-x\;$ and $\;\ln(1+x)<x$, and you can make any linear combination  of inequalities with positive coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

**I flipped the inequalities by mistake.**  However, I decided to keep this answer as I think it is interesting to know that
$$bx^2\leq (1-x)\ln(1-x)+(1+x)\ln(1+x)\leq cx^2\text{ for }x\in(-1,+1)$$
for all $b\leq 1$ and $c\geq \ln(4)$.  Other people showed that $c=\ln(4)$ is the smallest value of $c$.  I am showing that $b=1$ is the largest value of $b$.

---

I claim that $b=1$ works.  Observe that 
$$f(x):=(1-x)\ln(1-x)+(1+x)\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\,\big(\ln(1+u)-\ln(1-u)\big)\,\text{d}u\,,$$
for all $x\in[0,+1)$.  Now, $\ln(1+u)-\ln(1-u)\geq 2u$ for $u\in[0,+1)$; this is because $$\frac{1+u}{1-u}\geq 1+2u+2u^2+2u^3+2u^4\geq 1+2u+2u^2+2u^3+\frac{10}{3}u^4\geq \exp(2u)$$
for all $u\in[0,+1)$.
That is,
$$f(x)\geq \int_0^x\,(2u)\,\text{d}u=x^2\text{ for }x\in[0,+1)\,.$$
Indeed, we also have $f(x)\geq x^2$ when $x\in (-1,0]$, as $f$ is an even function.

To see why $b=1$ is the largest possible value, you only need to show that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\,\frac{(1-x)\,\ln(1-x)+(1+x)\,\ln(1+x)}{x^2}=1\,.$$
This can be done in many ways, and one method is using L'Hôpital's Rule twice.

Comment: Smaletst value of $c$ is not $2$, $c=1.5$ works too.

Comment: My bad.  The limit is $1$.  Hence, the smallest value of $c$ is indeed $1$.

Comment: At $c=1$, you have $(1-x)\ln(1-x) + (1+x)\ln (1+x) > x^2$ for all $0<x<1$.

$$c \ge \ln 4$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe  You are right.  I flipped the inequalities.